# find pattern in a column and replace it with awk

Tags: awk

I was trying to do the following.

I was trying to put column 1 when I found a pattern that would be "undefined", for example:

I have my file.txt file that contains

```
192.168.1.1, Paul

192.168.2.2, undefined
```

Here it is "undefined", then replace it with the first column in the row where it is "undefined". (192.168.2.2)

```
192.168.1.1, Paul

192.168.2.2, 192.168.2.2
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

using **awk**

```
$ awk -F", " '$2~/undefined/{ print $1 FS $1; next}1' file
192.168.1.1, Paul

192.168.2.2, 192.168.2.2
```

Comment: @ClaesWikner: Well, I want to specifically check $2 not the $0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.*\), undefined$/\1, \1/' file.txt
```

or

```
sed -r 's/(.*), undefined$/\1, \1/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This line works for your example, no matter the separator is `,` or `,(space)`

```
awk -F, '1+sub(/undefined$/,$1)' file
```